# Why does the greatest IEEE floating point representable number smaller than 1 differ from 1 by half a machine epsilon?

Tags: floating-point, numerical-methods

We can represent 1.0 as 2^0 x 1.0 and the greatest representable number smaller than 1.0 as k, where k = 2^0 x 0.111.......1 truncated to fit.

Then the difference or ulp for 1.0 - k = 2^0 x 0.00000.....1.

Isn't that the same as machine epsilon, where we have 
N
epsilon = 2^0 x 1.000000....1 - 2^0 x 1.000 = 2^0 x 0.000.....1?

Why is the correct value half?

Also, how would one calculate ulp for values other than 1.0?

Comment: Your title doesn't agree with your actual question, and asks why a falsehood is true.

Comment: @oldselflearner1959: Your title said the greatest representable value less than one was half an epsilon. It is not. It is one minus half an epsilon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A finite floating-point number is represented as a sign (+ or −), a fixed number *n*+1 of digits d<sub>0</sub>, d<sub>−1</sub>, d<sub>−2</sub>,  d<sub>−*n*</sub>, in some base *b*, and an exponent *e*, such that the number represented is *sign* d<sub>0</sub>.d<sub>−1</sub>d<sub>−2</sub>…d<sub>−*n*</sub> × *b*<sup>*e*</sup>. For this answer, we take the sign as + and *b* as 2.

With this representation:

- 1 is +1.00…0 × 2<sup>0</sup>.
- The next number higher than 1 is +1.00…1 × 2<sup>0</sup>. Since the d<sub>−*n*</sub> digit increased by 1, it exceeds 1 by 2<sup>0−*n*</sup>.
- The next number lower than 1 is +1.11…1 × 2<sup>−1</sup>. Note the exponent decreased. This means its d<sub>−*n*</sub> digit actually has the value 2<sup>−1−*n*</sup>. So it differs from 1 only by 2<sup>−1−*n*</sup> rather than 2<sup>0−*n*</sup>.

For any normal floating-point number, the ULP is *b*<sup>*e*−*n*</sup>. However, near the lower bounds of the floating-point format, IEEE 754 has subnormal numbers, and the ULP is clamped to a value of *b*<sup>*emin*−*n*</sup>.

Comment: Thanks for the really clear answer - it took me some time to get it but it's clear in the end. Also, what do you mean by the ULP value getting clamped to b^{1-n}? or is it b^{-1-n}?

Comment: @oldselflearner1959: Actually, for subnormal values, the exponent is clamped to a minimum value called *emin*, not 1. I have corrected my answer. For subnormal values, the exponent cannot decrease any further. Instead, the first digit(s) decrease to zero.